# Сжатие Mat изображения

Tags: c++, изображения, opencv

Всех приветствую.

В процессе работы с OpenCV столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Рабочий стол, размером 1920x1080, весит аж 382784 байтов!

Начал искать в документации способ сжатия изображения.

Нашел такую статью:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#bool%20imwrite(const%20String&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params)

В ней нашел такой код:

> C: int cvSaveImage(const char* filename, const CvArr* image, const
>   int* params=0 ) Parameters:    filename – Name of the file. image –
>   Image to be saved. params – Format-specific save parameters encoded as
>   pairs paramId_1, paramValue_1, paramId_2, paramValue_2, ... . The
>   following parameters are currently supported:
>
> For JPEG, it can be a quality ( CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY ) from 0 to
>   100 (the higher is the better). Default value is 95.

Как мне можно его сюда прикрутить?

Что-то типа такого:

int quality = 70;

imencode(".jpg", s, buf, quality);

Код:

```
Mat s;

vector<uchar> buf;

while (1) {
    r->GetDesktopMat(s);

    imencode(".jpg", s, buf);

    cout << buf.size() << endl; // 382784 - 1920x1080 resolution
}
```

Comment: А что, 400 кб - это много?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об описании параметров и способе их задания Вы можете прочесть [здесь](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite).

```
Mat s;

vector<uchar> buf;
vector<int> opts(2);

opts[0] = cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
opts[1] = 70;

while (1) {
    r->GetDesktopMat(s);
    imencode(".jpg", s, buf, opts);
}
```